# transfer listbox items from one asp.net page to another using session

Tags: asp.net, session, listbox, listboxitem

Transfer listbox items from one asp.net page to another using session.  I want to transfer the items of a list box from one asp.net page to another. The code somehow is throwing error. The items in the listbox are not being retrieved either.  I want to do the same with a check box list.  Hopefully the listbox issue will help[ me solve that too.  Please advice.

First Page

```
<asp:ListBox ID="SelectedItems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>     
<asp:Button ID="sbmtButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="152px" OnClick="sbmtButton_Click" />
```

.cs for the First Page

```
protected void sbmtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{Session["wrd"] = SelectedItems;Server.Transfer("~/aftrSubmit.aspx";);}
```

Second Page

.cs for the Second Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{if (!this.IsPostBack){Prescription_list = (ListBox)Session["wrd"];}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Page ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="SelectedItems" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="A"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="B"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="C"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="sbmtButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="152px" OnClick="sbmtButton_Click" />
```

**First Page C# Code-Behind:**

```
protected void sbmtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem[] x = new ListItem[SelectedItems.Items.Count];

    SelectedItems.Items.CopyTo(x, 0);

    Session["wrd"] = x;

    Server.Transfer("~/aftrSubmit.aspx");
}
```

**Second Page ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="Prescription_list" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

**Second Page C# Code-Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!this.IsPostBack)
   {
       ListItem[] x = (ListItem[])Session["wrd"];

       Prescription_list.Clear();
       Prescription_list.Items.AddRange(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But it did not help.  The values are still not carried on to the next page.  i want to transfer all the items of the listbox to the next page.

Comment: The original code I provided only adds the selected items from the listbox. I now updated my code to add ALL items.

Comment: Still not working.  It is not throwing any errors but is not carrying the values.

Comment: Please post all your updated code. I have tested this myself and its working for me. You need to show the ASPX page for both Page1 and Page2 Please.